# Problem inserting multiple values using SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I have the following insert statement which works fine on one system running SQL Server 2008 but I've tried the same thing on a system running 2000 and it gives an error...

Is there an easy fix for this since I have over 3000 records to insert and I don't want to have to do them all one at a time!

```
INSERT INTO uk_postcodes (outcode, lat, lng) 
VALUES ('AB12', '57.098381', '-2.172400'),('AB13', '57.108', '-2.237')
```

Comment: The ability to specify more than one tuple for INSERT is a new feature in the 2008 version - doesn't exist before that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using SQL server 2000, there are two ways to do this -

one is

```
INSERT INTO uk_postcodes (outcode, lat, lng) 
VALUES ('AB12', '57.098381', '-2.172400');
INSERT INTO uk_postcodes (outcode, lat, lng) 
VALUES ('AB13', '57.108', '-2.237');
```

Second way is using UNION ALL-

```
INSERT INTO uk_postcodes (outcode, lat, lng) 
SELECT 'AB12', '57.098381', '-2.172400'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'AB13', '57.108', '-2.237'
```

Comment: I managed to find and replace using your first suggestion... thanks

Comment: I just learn that SQL SERVER 2000 does not support insert multiple rows

Answer (score 4):

With a bit of string replacing you will be able to convert the script into the following which should work:

```
INSERT INTO uk_postcodes (outcode, lat, lng) 
select 'AB12', '57.098381', '-2.172400' union select 'AB13', '57.108', '-2.237'
```

Answer (score 1):

Both answers give will work.  For more information:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_(SQL)
ANSI SQL-92 added the multi-records insert syntax, separating VALUES using comma, which is what you are trying to use.  For SQL-Server specifically, support for this syntax was added since version 2008.

- Syntax of INSERT: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx
- Syntax of Table value constructor*: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx
- Examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776381.aspx

  - (B. Inserting multiple rows of data)

For speed, there are some issues with overly long strings, so use the

```
SELECT .. UNION
SELECT ..
```

form, but break and start another INSERT after about 100 or 1000 records.

* table value constructors are not limited to the INSERT statement only. SQL Server 2008 goes one further to allow it to define a `<derived table>`, e.g.

```
SELECT MAX(Amount)
FROM (
     VALUES (1),(2),(192),(99)
) Tbl(Amount)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you all your data is like that try replacing all **"),("** with **");INSERT INTO uk_postcodes (outcode, lat, lng) VALUES ("**